# HTML select options close div

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to JavaScript, so this might be very easy for a lot of you.

I have a HTML select object with some options in it. The whole SELECT is in a small div. The only thing I like to achieve is to close the div everytime I clock on one of the options. Now, every option does something else, that's no problem. But I can't seem to tell all of them to close this div. Is it something about this.id ??

Thanks

Comment: use jQuery to do this.....it will be much easier for you with it

Comment: What is "close the div" means for you?

Answer (score 0):

give id to that div...for my example suppose it is 'Div' and try this code...
     `<form name='template'>
<select name='choise' onchange="javascript:hideDiv()">

<option value="uniquename">uniquename</option>

</select>

</form>`
and script code is
 `function hideDiv(){

if(document.getElementById('Div').style.display != "none") {         document.getElementById('Div').style.display = "none"; }}`